# PHP - Strategy for renewing cookie and session in one page application

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I've seen this post: [What's a good strategy for renewing the expiration of a forms auth ticket between .net and php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636061/whats-a-good-strategy-for-renewing-the-expiration-of-a-forms-auth-ticket-betwee)

That post suggests renewing the cookie on every PHP page the user accesses. What if I am designing a one-page application, which of the following works or what better **methods are there to renew the session and cookie to let the user stay logged in?**

---

#### Scenario:

1. A user is on a page writing a long post, which would cost him >30mins. The cookie remains 30mins until expire.
2. Suppose even if the cookie got renewed, the user left the public PC that he was using and forgot to logout. After a lengthy time of inactivity, the application should be able to log itself out.

Do I...

1. Ajax POST to renew the cookie and session upon every click and key press? (sounds like a ridiculous work load)
2. Display a popup before cookie expires that let user renew cookie on button press. (sounds annoying)

---

#### Questions to sum up:

- What methods are there to renew the session and cookie to let the user stay logged in in a one-page application?
- Also, how does StackOverflow and other platforms manage to let user stay logged in so seamlessly, what techniques might they be using?

Answer (score 1):

Use a recurring (once a minute for example) ajax-call to a simple backend-script, that re-sets the session-cookie and updates the session-file ... super simple.

Comment: What if the user is on a public PC and forgot to log out?

Comment: Bad luck ... if the user just closes the browser tho, the ajax-call won’t be made, and the cookie will expire normally.
I use this technique myself ... and I combine it with a cookie, that expires after 3 minutes ... pretty safe :)

Comment: I don't always believe what big companies do are the absolute correct ways. I mean you've seen Facebook pranks, right? :)

Comment: This is probably not what Facebook does. I wouldn’t know ... this is what I do, it works flawlessly and it is far safer than 'normal' sessions that expire after 30 or 60 minutes.